# syntax error in from clause. vb 2012

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, syntax-error

Dim con As New OleDbConnection

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MedicalSys.accdb"

    con.Open()

    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Add Form", con)

    da.Fill(dt)


    Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
```

That's my code but when i run it this line will give me an error:

da.Fill(dt)

I dont know exactly what the problem is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for [the simplest SELECT clause](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) is

```
SELECT <list of fields comma separated> FROM <tablename>
```

So your query is not syntactically correct

It should be

```
SELECT * FROM ????
```

We don't know the table name that you want to read, so when you have found the correct table name replace the question marks with your table. Keep in mind that if the table name contains space you need to encapsulate the name with square brackets (I.E.  `[My Table Name]`)

Comment: Ok thank you Sir, But now i have another problem it is selecting the right table but it is giving me an error saying that column 7 cannot be found.

Comment: Cannot see anywhere the reference to the column 7. Please add your whole code. By the way, how many columns are present in your, with still unknonw name, table

Comment: Table name is Add Form

Comment: `       newRow.Item("Student ID") = Student_IDTextBox.Text
        newRow.Item("Student Name") = Student_NameTextBox.Text
        newRow.Item("[Date of Birth]") =  Date_of_BirthDateTimePicker.Text
        newRow.Item("Address") = AddressTextBox.Text
        newRow.Item("E-mail") = E_mailTextBox.Text
        newRow.Item("Allergies") = AllergiesTextBox.Text
        newRow.Item("[Emergency Contact Number]") = Emergency_Contact_NumberTextBox.Text`

Comment: But my student Id field is a primary key could that be the reason why it is giving that error? @steve

Comment: Are you trying an insert? If yes and your Student ID field is an autonumber field, then you cannot set the value yourself. (Autonumber means that you expect the database to fill it). However given the complexity of the code, I suggest to open a new question and close this if the original problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Steve:

If your table name contains spaces or any reserved word, you need to put the table name inside brackets like:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Add Form]", con)
```

Here I assume, that your table is named `Add Form`.